# How to remove a median point in a bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component, navbar

Im creating component that is just a bootstrap navbar, and i got and issue that is that between each of my nav-item i got a median point that is displaying. I have never put in any code for this to appear and there is no reference to this in the bootstrap docoumentation. and the comportement of this point is quite erratic as on some computer the  point is on top of the link instead of between them.

```
<template>
 <div>
<b-navbar type="dark" variant="info"  fixed="top" >
  <b-navbar-brand >Kisdis</b-navbar-brand>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#1" class="a">sample1 </b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#2" class="a">sample2</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#3" class="a">sample3</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#4" class="a">sample4</b-nav-item>
</b-navbar>
</div>
  </template>
```

And the CSS, if this is relevant

```
a:link {
  color: white;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: white;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: white;
}
```

here is a visual of what it's curently doing

[image: and here is the result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out to wrap your items with `<b-navbar-nav>` component :

```
div>
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="info">
 <b-navbar-brand >Kisdis</b-navbar-brand>
<b-navbar-nav>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#1" class="a">sample1 </b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#2" class="a">sample2</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#3" class="a">sample3</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item color="white" href="#4" class="a">sample4</b-nav-item>
</b-navbar-nav>

  </b-navbar>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks, it worked, but if possible could you explain why it did/ wy it was doing this? im genuinely curious

Comment: you're welcome, I think nav items are styled like `ul>li {list-style:none}` and `b-navbar-nav` is using that `ul`